# Book style edition

Tags: books

I would like to be able to create my own layout to write my class notes, in book mode. But I don't know anything about editing, can you recommend a book or article dedicated to editing of this type? Any comment is welcome.

Greetings

Comment: It seems more like you're looking for something like LyX - a WYSIWYG-like LaTeX GUI.

Comment: Is your question about how to create a modification of the `book` document class with your own layout?

Comment: @WillieWong Exactly, that's what I was thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several comments, mashed together to pretend to be an answer:

1. I would not suggest editing the book class directly. It is usually a lot easier to `\LoadClass{book}` to pick up many of the pre-defined things, and then start modifying them. There are lots of packages that make such edits easier (make sure to study their user manuals):

   - `geometry`, as its name suggests, helps you set the geometry of the page.
   - `titlesec` is one of several packages that helps you configure how section/chapter titles appear in your document; its companion packages `titleps` and `titletoc` helps you configure the page style (headers and footers) and table of contents
   - another commonly used package for setting the page style is `fancyhdr`
   - for table of contents, [there are a lot of packages](https://ctan.org/recommendations/tocloft) for dealing with various aspects.
2. For the mechanics of writing a document class, you will need to study the [*LaTeX for package and class authors*](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/clsguide.pdf) document.
3. Another option is for you to forgo writing a class yourself, and instead switch to a highly customizable class like [memoir](https://ctan.org/pkg/memoir?lang=en); whether you end up using the class or not, it is good to browse through its user manual, as it does a very good job presenting the various items to consider when designing how to layout a book.
4. It is not possible to reach perfection with the first try. Be prepared that designing your own document class is bound to be an iterative process. (For example, [my personal class for lecture notes](https://gitlab.msu.edu/wongwil2/www-textools/-/tree/master/texmf/tex/latex/wwwcls?ref_type=heads) is in its 6th or 7th iteration of redesign.)

Comment: Nice. Just to add, there's also "A Few Notes on Book Design" from Peter Wilson (the initiator of memoir) https://mirror.dogado.de/tex-archive/info/memdesign/memdesign.pdf .